# How to use concat() method in wql?

Tags: mysql, wmi, wmi-query, wmic, wql

I am develop wmi application to get windows logs by using WQL query.
How to use CONCAT() method in that query.

Input WQL Query :

```
wmic -U XXX%XXX //XXX "Select CONCAT(Category, '|DHCP') from Win32_NTLogEvent where TimeWritten > '06/04/2014 13:59:00' and Logfile = 'Security'"
```

Output :

```
[wmi/wmic.c:212:main()] ERROR: Retrieve result data.
NTSTATUS: NT code 0x80041017 - NT code 0x80041017
```

Without using CONCAT() method, it will work perfectly. if any other way to get value using CONCAT() method in WQL.

**Notes:** 
When i using CONCAT() method in different scenario, it is not working. it will throw error code.

Please Help me Guys.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `CONCAT(Category, '|DHCP') AS some_alias` ?

Comment: i am not using any alias. if it possible please comment full query with alias name.

Comment: my comment is proposing you to try using one

Comment: wmic -U XXX%XXX //XXX "Select concat(Category, '|DHCP', CategoryString) AS ab from Win32_NTLogEvent where TimeWritten > '06/04/2014 13:59:00' and Logfile = 'Security'".   This query also return error... any other way? please do something?

Answer (score 1):

The is not `CONCAT` function in [`WQL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the WQL is just a a small subset of the SQL standard and doesn't include such function.